# What's the meaning of "out" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From CNN Student News:[CNN Student News Jan 22, 2014](http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1401/22/sn.01.html)

> But in Ohio, there is a state of emergency. More than ten percent of people who live there use propane tanks or heating oil to keep their homes warm. And the icy weather coincides with a rare shortage of both. The state of emergency will allow trucks that carry the fuel to work longer hours.
> ***Out west***, a very different kind of emergency in California. A drought. The worst ever recorded there has dried up lakes and reservoirs, worsened wildfires and killed off crops.

What's the meaning of **out** in **out west** here? Does it have the same meaning of the word **out** in **go out to the west of the America**?

Comment: There were many people *out there.* The word **out** in such context means *away from the place you are standing in or talking from*. This probably means *out there in west, a very different...*

Comment: I second Maulik. That sentence doesn't seem to be formal in sense. Just an informal usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Maulik in his comments the word [out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Out) in such contexts  means somewhere away from a position.

However for this particular example it has a very specific meaning. In fact **Out** in "Out West" does not has its individual meaning.

**Out west** here is used as an Idiom that refers to the "Western part of the United States". You can find the reference [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Out+West).

It usually refers to the states of California, Idaho, Nevada, Arizona etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite like when we say, "up north" or "down south". Come to think of it, Americans seldom say "out east". Hmmm. "Back east", maybe?
This is odd, indeed, but there you have it.

Comment: Might west coasters say "out east"?